# Unable to create empty memory layer for Line layer using PyQGIS?

Tags: shapefile, pyqgis, python-2.7, vector-layer

```
# Get the currently selected layer
inLayer = iface.activeLayer()

# Get its list of fields
inFields = inLayer.dataProvider().fields()

# Convert its geometry type enum to a string we can pass to
# QgsVectorLayer's constructor
inLayerGeometryType = ['Point','Line','Polygon'][inLayer.geometryType()]

# Convert its CRS to a string we can pass to QgsVectorLayer's constructor
inLayerCRS = inLayer.crs().authid()

# Make the output layer
outLayer = QgsVectorLayer(inLayerGeometryType + '?crs='+inLayerCRS, \
inLayer.name() + u'_copy', \
'memory')

# Copy the fields from the old layer into the new layer
outLayer.startEditing()
outLayer.dataProvider().addAttributes(inFields.toList())
outLayer.commitChanges()

# Add it to the map
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(outLayer)
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(outLayer, 'temp_Layer.shp',"utf-8", None, "ESRI Shapefile")
```

works with Polygon Layer and Point Layer, but in case of line layer its creating minidump!

Comment: Dont use + to combine paths and names. Use os.path.join

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are constructing a layer description with `Line`:

```
L = QgsVectorLayer("Line?crs=EPSG:4326","foo","memory")
```

and you don't test it. If you did you would see:

```
L.isValid()
# False
```

The correct descriptor needs `Linestring`:

```
L = QgsVectorLayer("Linestring?crs=EPSG:4326","foo","memory")
L.isValid()
# True
```

I'm not sure where this is documented, I hit it by trial and error once I saw that `Line` was wrong. I'm surprised the string version of the geometry isn't in the layer somewhere which would save you having to decode the numeric geometry type....

Actually, it looks like you are trying to do *exactly* what this answerer was trying to do back in August:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45818097/211116

Doc for memory layer construction is here - note there are more than just the three geometry types you expect in your code:

https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#memory-provider

Comment: Nearly 3 days trying to figure this out..Thanks!